# How do I hide text but keep icons on a small screen?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to hide the words, Home/Reservations/myReservations/About/Settings when the screen gets smaller BUT I want the icons to still be visible on a smaller screen. I am currently using:

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id='test' ng-click="doTheBack()"><a class="navbar-brand"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>Back</a></div>
         <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">


        </div>
      <div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <a class="navbar-brand visible-lg" href="/landingIndex.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> Reservation</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myReservation"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> MyReservations</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#settings"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> Settings</a>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `a`'s `font-size` property to 0 then set the icons font size back to a desired amount

Code:

```
@media (max-width:550px) {
  a {
      font-size: 0px !important;
  }

   a i {
      font-size: 20px !important;
   }
}
```

[example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/MaVPKp?editors=110) you need to resize the screen below 550px for the effect to take place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap these words in a span and give them a class like so:

```
<a class="navbar-brand visible-lg" href="/landingIndex.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span class="link-title">Home</span></a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> <span class="link-title">Reservation</span></a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#myReservation"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><span class="link-title">My Reservations</span></a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> <span class="link-title">About</span></a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#settings"><i class="fa fa-gear"></i> <span class="link-title">Settings</span></a>
```

Then, using CSS media queries, hide elements with specified class ("link-title" in this example):

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .link-title {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the use of **hidden-sm** **hidden-xs** class of bootstrap you can easily achieve this.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<a class="navbar-brand visible-lg" href="/landingIndex.html">
 <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
  <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Home</span>
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> 
  <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Reservation</span>
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#myReservation">
   <i class="fa fa-list"></i> 
   <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">MyReservations</span>
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#about">
   <i class="fa fa-shield"></i> 
   <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">About</span>
</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#settings">
   <i class="fa fa-gear"></i> 
   <span class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">Settings</span>
</a>
</ul>
```